# How to execute this code only when user signed in

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I've been trying to add this code to update the player's score after game over, it works as i want it when the user is signed in, but if the user is not signed in, the game crashes

```
void game_over() {
    num_lifes = 0;
    findViewById(R.id.hero).setEnabled(false);
    findViewById(R.id.btn_play).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    show_lifes();
    Games.getLeaderboardsClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
            .submitScore(getString(R.string.leaderboard_id), score);

    findViewById(R.id.game_over).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a function or convenience method in your User instance to check for login you would just use

```
void game_over() {
    if (isSignedIn) {
        num_lifes = 0;
        findViewById(R.id.hero).setEnabled(false);
        findViewById(R.id.btn_play).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        show_lifes();
        Games.getLeaderboardsClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
            .submitScore(getString(R.string.leaderboard_id), score);

        findViewById(R.id.game_over).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

And your isSignedIn method would look like this

```
private boolean isSignedIn() {
  return GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(context) != null;
}
```

Comment: I changed the position of " if isSignedIn " a little bit , because it would crash for another reason if i leave like that ^^